# How to open finder on Mac OS X automatically when USB plugged in?

Tags: macos, usb, usb-drive

Super simple question, but I can't fond the answer.

I want the Finder to open mounted disk when I plug in USB drive... How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you @mark-setchell

I've ended up with this Apple Script for my /Volumes folder:

```
on adding folder items to this_folder after receiving added_items
    try
        tell application "Finder"
            --open window and activate finder 
            activate
            --open the USB
            open added_items
        end tell
    end try
end adding folder items to
```

So every time some new item appears in /Volumes folder Finder opens window and selects this item.

This solution has some delay before opening finder (5-10 sec). I guess Folder Actions just work this way...

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this by adding a `Folder Action` to the folder `Volumes` which is where external disks get mounted. AFAIK, you can only do that in the Finder and the `/Volumes` folder is set invisible in the Finder - thanks, Apple.

So, first make the `/Volumes` folder visible to the Finder, by starting the Terminal and running

```
sudo SetFile -a v /Volumes
```

Now, start the Finder and select your System drive and then `Macintosh HD` on the left pane. You should now see

- Applications
- Library
- System
- User
- Volumes

Right-click on the `Volumes` folder and go to `Setup Folder Actions` and attach the `add - new item` script. You can then diddle around with that to do whatever you want the Finder to do when a disk is inserted.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @MarkSetchell's answer, to make the /Volumes folder visible I had to use `sudo chflags nohidden /Volumes` instead. However an easier way to make this folder visible (and Temporarily, which might be preferred) is with a key combination:

> Cmd (⌘) + Shift + .

(also my context menu item is `Services > Folder Actions Setup`)

And to save others the pain, the folder these scripts are saved in is `/Library/Scripts/Folder Action Scripts` (I'm ashamed to say it took me a few hours to find it)

Create a new file there using the terminal and sudo, paste the script above, and add it in folder actions setup. It works like a charm (for me at least).